# Stuck in javascript.working with html canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am creating a website and I wanted to use the html canvas in it. I got a code snippet from codepen and I am now stuck. Can any one help me?

HTML

```
<canvas id='canvas' width="1520" height="760"></canvas>
<script src="jsss.js"></script>
```

javascript

jsss.js

```
(function ($, window) {

}($, window));


// Init plugin
$('canvas').constellation({
    star: {
        width: 3
    },
    line: {
        color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, .5)'
    },
    length: (window.innerWidth / 6),
    radius: (window.innerWidth / 5)
});
```

The the error I am getting is:

> ReferenceError: `$` is not defined

Comment: Have you tried including jQuery before jsss.js?

Comment: you have jsss.js this file in your project and put codepen link in your question

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help you if you told us exactly what you're trying to accomplish. What is "constellation" supposed to do? You could also link to the _pen_ you got the code from

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to load [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) to get that to work.

The dollar sign (`$`) isn't a special symbol in JavaScript the same way it is in some other languages, but jQuery turns it into a function that you can call with a [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CSS_Selector) as the argument. Then you can call methods on the object returned by that function call.

In your example, it looks like you're trying to call a `constellation` method on a jQuery object created for the `canvas` element. That function would probably be made available by a jQuery plugin. So, you've got two things to install for that to work: jQuery and the "constellation" plugin.

It's worth noting that jQuery is mostly an obsolete technology. JavaScript has been changed and improved since jQuery was at the height of its popularity and it's just not worth the overhead to use the library any more. You shouldn't build any new code using jQuery.

If [this](https://codepen.io/acauamontiel/pen/mJdnw) is the *pen* you're referencing, the author is using [Zepto](https://zeptojs.com/) as an alternative to jQuery. It says so in the code comments and it's referenced in the JavaScript settings. It looks like the focus of the library is to address some of the concerns of the overhead added by using jQuery while supporting the same syntax. Still, it's unnecessary overhead and you can do all of that with no overhead and standard JavaScript syntax.

Comment: tqsm it helped me.

Answer (score 0):

If your custom script is loaded before the jQuery plugin is loaded to the browser then this type of problem may occur. So, always keep your own JavaScript or jQuery code after calling the jQuery plugin so the solution for this is :

First add the link to the jQuery file hosted at GoogleApis or a local jQuery file that you will download from https://jquery.com/download/ and host on your server:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or any plugin for jQuery. Then put your custom script file link or code:

```
<script src="js/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: no after adding the script also it is showing the same error and also it stated that it is failed to load the googleapis.